# Script : classList.add . Класс добавляется по событии "кнопка", но по окончании скрипта, удаляется. Почему

Tags: javascript

```js
var btnleft = document.getElementById('btn-left');
const elem = document.getElementById('ms');
btnleft.onclick = function() {
  alert("start");
  elem.classList.add("fon-left");
  alert("end");
}
```

```html
<div class="main-slide" id="ms">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slide-flex">
      <div class="btn-left">
        <a href="" id="btn-left">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Я думаю, что у вас просто страница перезагружается, т.к. клик по ссылки. Почитайте про метод  [.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) или можете использовать `return false;` в callback-функции.

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно страница перегружается. "return false;" решает данную проблему

Comment: Страница перезагружается, т.к. действие клик происходит по ссылке. Решение в данном случае поменять в html  разметке ссылку на кнопку.